# ImportError: cannot import name 'lapack_lite'

Tags: numpy

operating system: MacOS

I am trying to use a program called Infant FreeSurfer, but it is unable to find 'lapack_lite'. I believe the issue may be related to numpy, which is correctly updated but does not associate anything with the 'lapack_lite' command.

How can I resolve this?

Here is my problem in detail from the terminal:

```
from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite, _umath_linalg
```

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'lapack_lite'
```

I already tried to Install an older version of numpy: It is complicated, and I haven't been able to do it. I believe it creates incompatibilities.

I really need to solve
thank you for your help